# Java program not printing all ASCII values

Tags: java

I have written a Java program which prints the corresponding ASCII values of the statement I give as input. The problem is that, it is not printing all the values.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the string to be converted");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str =input.next();
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();
        int i =0;
        for(i =0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            int ascii=(int)ch[i];   
            System.out.println(ascii+"\n");
        }

        input.close();
    }
}
```

For ex :- "The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in" it is printing just 84,104,101.

It should print all the values in the sentence.

Comment: Which values is it not printing ?

Comment: Kindly post your actual and expected output.

Comment: For ex :- "The oldest classical Greek and Latin writing had little or no space between words, and could be written in" it is printing just 84,104,101

Comment: so space is not printing

Comment: you are using `next()` which reads a token in your case it will read `The` instead you should `nextLine()` which reads the whole line check http://ideone.com/FqsdG3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = input.next();
```

should be:

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```

[Scanner#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

[Scanner#nextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

Comment: let me try, i think this is the problem

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem, i will accept the answer in some time, i will accept this answer as you answered before others.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 String str =input.nextLine();
```

One more way to get `ASCII` values.

```
String s = "The oldest classical Greek";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("US-ASCII");
for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
System.out.println(bytes[i]);//prints ASCIIs
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of [`scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) (Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner).

Change it to

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
String str = input.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.next()` reads a token instead of a line against your expectation.

You need to use

```
String str = input.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
String str = input.next();
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](https://ideone.com/bk0SXl)**